# Cannot setup boost properly

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

I'm using windows.
I tried both tutorials (Unix and windows) from boost main page but I can't set up boost properly. Finally, i used [this link](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html), but its still not working:

```
$ gcc -I/c/MinGW/include -std=c++14 a.cpp -o a
```

> a.cpp:1:35: fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or
>   directory compilation terminated.

After `cd /c/MinGW/include` I get to root directory of boost, so its not an issue.

Comment: So all the header files and subdirectories of Boost lies *directly* in `/c/MinGW/include`? They should be in a sub-directory `/c/MinGW/include/boost`. So you should have e.g. `/c/MinGW/include/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp`.

Comment: cygwin and mingw on the same line... no good. Can you locate "/c/MinGW/include/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp"? Anyway, try Visual Studio. Less pain ;)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I have it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Performing the following two steps would make your IDE aware of Boost:

**1.** set `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` to the root boost installation directory (where boost include directories exist) ex. `C:\boost\boost_1_x_y` (on Windows example).

**2.** use `find_package()` cmake function for cmake to locate Boost.

Ex. partial cmake script to include Boost in a simple c++ project on windows (Bearing in mind I am using CLion):

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/boost/boost_1_70_0/)

find_package(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

Hope that helps